# Does PFN_LIST_CORRUPT error always indicate bad RAM?

Tags: memory

I'm receiving a `PFN_LIST_CORRUPT` BSOD after a few minutes of using my Dell D600 laptop (running Windows XP).  Based on my searches, it seems this is typically related to bad RAM.  I haven't had other problems, and nothing has changed on this computer.  Could it be that one of the RAM chips has come unseated, or is it just corrupted and I should get a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't speak for that error, but there's one way to easily rule it out - run a memory testing application.

[Memtest+](http://www.memtest.org/) does the trick nicely.  Download and burn the ISO, boot off it and let it run for 24-48 hours - if it picks up errors, you definitely need new memory.  If not, then you can continue troubleshooting with some reasonable evidence that your memory is fine behind you.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be surprised at how many times RAM will become ever-so-slightly unseated.  Power off the unit, open it up, and reseat the RAM.  If the issue continues, you can at least rule that out, and if it doesn't, it's fixed. :)

As for testing the ram, @Greg Work [has a good suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/6686/does-pfnlistcorrupt-error-always-indicate-bad-ram/6777#6777), although keep in mind that the test can occasionally fail to detect bad RAM; but overall, it's just Good Enough(tm).

Comment: For the sake of thoroughness: *"Power off the unit,"* **and disconnect the power**.